# Parsing text within block "|-" and "|- or }"

Tags: python

Are there any built-in python prototypes to achieve the following?can anyone suggest how can the following be done..

I am trying to get all the data within `[ ]` and split based on `\s+` for lines that start with `|` between the block `|-` and `|-` or `}`

```
   {| border=&quot;1&quot; cellspacing=&quot;1&quot; cellpadding=&quot;1&quot;
    |-
    Ignore block
    |-
    | [http://data/code SEC.12.0]
    | [file://data\\loc \\DATA\LOC]&lt;br&gt;
    |
    [file://\\ftp\\location \\ftp\\location]&amp;nbsp;&lt;br&gt; &lt;br&gt; &

    |-
    | [http://data/code2 SEC.13.0]
    | [file://data\\loc2 \\DATA\LOC2]&lt;br&gt;]
    |
    [file://\\ftp\\location2 \\ftp\\location2]&amp;nbsp;&lt;br&gt; &lt;br&gt; &
    |
    }
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:-

```
SEC.12.0
\\DATA\LOC
\\ftp\\location


SEC.13.0
\\DATA\LOC2
\\ftp\\location2
```

Comment: How much of that HTML escaping is real - where is this data coming from? Looks like mangled wikimarkup

Comment: @Eric - the text is from a wiki but the code looks exactly the same

Comment: I find it hard to believe the wiki contains `&quot;` characters. You're scraping the wrong view on the page here.

Comment: @Eric - we can ignore that now.we dont have to parse that...only the data betweeen |- and |- or } need to be parsed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
import re

data = []

for block in re.findall(r'(?s)\|-(.+?)(?=\|-|})', text):
    r = [x.split()[-1] for x in re.findall(r'\[(.+?)\]', block)]
    if r:
        data.append(r)

print data
```

Result:

```
[['SEC.12.0', '\\DATA\\LOC', '\\ftp\\location'], ['SEC.13.0', '\\DATA\\LOC2', '\\ftp\\location2']]
```